# Showing memory usage bar under drive icon LEFT in Explorer

Tags: windows-7, memory, icons, hard-drive

So it is one nice utility I had in my WinXP that shows memory usage bar under the drive icon LEFT in Explorer:

[image] 
Vista drive icon shows it like this:

[image: That is where I need to see memory usage]

It calls [Vista Drive Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnZfa.jpg). This also shows `"!"` when there is a critical free memory size on drive. How to make it in Windows 7? Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set Explorer to "Tiles" display to get the bars under the drives in Windows 7.

Click Here:

[image: ClickHere]

Choose "Tiles":

[image: ChooseTiles]

You can also switch between icon size/types by holding Ctrl and rolling your mousewheel, while over an active Explorer Window.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set a specific view (e.g.: list, details etc.).
I don't know how this menu-option is called in english, so I made a screenshot for you. You should be able to select it by position (the second from the bottom):

[image],

**Update 2011\11\20 16:08**:
AFAIK, you can't show a memory-usage-bar in the tree on the left side. 
You need an extension that does that like that extension that you used in your Windows XP.